# tool-tip positioning inside the canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, chart.js, tooltip

I am trying to position tool-tip inside the canvas

.this is the code i have got for postion and displaying.

```
`var position = this._chart.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
tooltipEl.style.position = 'absolute';
tooltipEl.style.left = (position.left + window.pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX) + 'px';
tooltipEl.style.top = (position.top + window.pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY) + 'px';`
```